# Nav border bottom following mouse

Tags: javascript, css, menu, border

Does anyone what how to create the bottom border on a menu that would follow your cursor?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question? It's unclear what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Comment: Thanks, chriz! Didn't even know that it was called magicline!